# Spritekit Collision Detection not functioning properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am using SpriteKit to build a game and have run into some trouble with collision detection. I have 2 subclasses of `SKSpriteNode`, `Player` and `Enemy`. They should both detect collisions with each other. Here's how I am initializing the `Player` object's `physicsBody`:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory;
```

And here's how I am initializing the `Enemy` objects's `physicsBody`:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = NO;
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
```

I have my `GameScene` implementing the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol and I have this in its init:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0);
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

And yet, the `didBeginContact` method isn't being called as it should be. I tried initializing the `physicsBodies` after the objects are created in the scene and still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the code that makes the `bitMasks`, it's in a `Common.h` file that is imported in `Prefix.pch` file.

```
static const uint32_t enemyCategory = 0x1 <<0;
static const uint32_t playerCategory = 0x1 <<1;
```

Comment: Where and how have you set the bitmask category values? Please post some code related to that.

Comment: Set the dynamic property to YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set physicsBody.dynamic to YES for your nodes.

From the SKPhysicsBody class reference:

> dynamic
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether the physics body is
> moved by the physics simulation.
>
> The default value is YES. If the value is NO, then the physics body
> ignores all forces and impulses applied to it.